# How to pass specific table values to ajax which we get from a database table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Example
This is index.php file
Form this file i pass value `$abc` which stores all values of table to ajax when any selection is select from `ALL Work Spaces` and i want to chnge result in `Size` Selection

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");
$abc=mysql_query("select * from table_name");
?>
<select onchange="showSoft(this.value)" > 
      <option value="" selected="selected">All Work Spaces </option>
      <option value="industrial">Workshop/Industrial </option> 
</select>
<select name="tosize" id="tosize">
<option selected>Size</option>
<option value="100" id="softsq1">100sq ft </option>
<option value="200" id="soft2">200sq ft </option>
<option value="300" id="soft1">300sq ft </option>
</select>
<script>
function showSoft(str) {
  var xhttp;
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("softsq1").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
      }
  };
  xhttp.open('GET', 'two.php?q='+str+'&w=<?php echo $abc; ?>', true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

Now see two.php file code
In this file they check all values from `$abc` by fatching but it shows fatal error please help me how to pass that table values ?

```
<?php
$ab=$_REQUEST['w'];
$result=mysql_fetch_array($ab);
echo $result[0];
?>
```

If you have any other trick please help me becoz it not return value it returne fatal error

Comment: You are trying to pass a _mysql resultset_ as a URL param, and it is not possible. Try to get the result of the query and parse it as json.

Comment: first your code is old as time mysql is long gone use mysqli, second you don't connect to a db in two.php, 3th why don;t you connect to the db in two.php?

Comment: madalin so i also connect db in two.php file?

Comment: yes man but use mysqli

Comment: but i only know mysql :-(

Comment: and i was also try to connect db in two.php but same shows fatal error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to get the values in your *one.php* file, serialize the result array and urlencode it to parse in your ajax url call, and finally undecode  and unserialize the string in your *two.php* file.

So, get the result array first:

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
mysql_select_db("databasename");
$abc=mysql_query("select * from table_name");
$results = mysql_fetch_array($abc, MYSQL_ASSOC);
?>
```

In your ajax request parse it as json string:

```
xhttp.open('GET', 'two.php?q='+str+'&w=<?php echo urlencode(serialize($results)); ?>', true);
```

And check finally in your **two.php** file to unserialize the json string to an array:

```
<?php
$ab=$_REQUEST['w'];
$results = unserialize(urldecode($ab));
print_r($results);
?>
```

By the way, pay attention:

> **mysql_fetch_array** was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be
>   used.

Comment: thanx for ans but from w it pass      a%3A7%3A%7Bs%3A2%3A%22id%22%3Bs%3A1%3A%221%22%3Bs%3A3%3A%22url%22%3Bs%3A21%3A%22+%24_POST%5B%22bwdspo_url%22%5D%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22title%22%3Bs%3A22%3A%22%24_POST%5B%22bwdspo_title%22%5D%22%3Bs%3A5%3A%22image%22%3Bs%3A22%3A%22%24_POST%5B%22upload_image%22%5D%22%3Bs%3A7%3A%22content%22%3Bs%3A24%3A%22%24_POST%5B%22bwdspo_content%22%5D%22%3Bs%3A8%3A%22Category%22%3Bs%3A0%3A%22%22%3Bs%3A4%3A%22Date%22%3Bs%3A10%3A%220000-00-00%22%3B%7D                                                              this type of val and i want to show by col name of table on two.php

Comment: I mistook the order of decoding and unserialize. the correct way is: `$results = unserialize(urldecode($ab));` (the answer is updated now)

Comment: ohk in two.php file?

Comment: Sure. in **two.php** file.

Comment: but on two.php file can we use this also while($results = unserialize(urldecode($ab)){    if($results['ur']=='abc'){ i++; }  }

Answer (score 0):

## I suggest you to use $.ajax:

```
function showSoft(str) {
$.ajax({
     method: "GET",
     data: xxx,
     url: xxx,

     success: function (data) {
     console.log(data);
          },
    error: function(data) {
        //xxxxxxx
           }
    });
}
```

Here just pass what you want in data

Comment: thanx for ans but in data: how i add or pass two values to two.php page? its format?

Comment: and they give access to pass table values? after fatching or before fatching?

Comment: yeah you can pass Json, table, or vars just put it between brackets data: {var1, var2}

Comment: ohk thanx Ammar for this :-)